# ChannelsLiveServerTestCase equivalent for pytest

Tags: pytest, django-channels, pytest-django, asgi

In pytest-django there is a builtin fixture [`live_server`](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#live-server) though it seems like this server (that is actually based on [`LiveServerTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase)) can't handle web-sockets or at least won't interact with my `asgi.py` module.

How can one mimic that fixture in order to use `ChannelsLiveServerTestCase` instead? Or anything else that will run a test-database and will be able to serve an ASGI application?

My goal eventually is to have as close to production environment as possible, for testing and being able to test interaction between different Consumers.

P.S: I know I can run `manage.py testserver <Fixture>` on another thread / process by overriding [`django_db_setup`](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#django-db-setup) though I seek for a better solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@aaron's solution can't work, due to pytest-django [conservative approach](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html) for database access.

another proccess wouldn't be aware that your test has database access permissions therefore you won't have database access. ([here is a POC](https://github.com/nrbnlulu/channels_pytest_liveserver))

Using a session scoped fixture of daphne `Server`  was enough for me.

```py
import threading
import time

from functools import partial

from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import ASGIStaticFilesHandler
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.db import connections
from django.test.utils import modify_settings

from daphne.server import Server as DaphneServer
from daphne.endpoints import build_endpoint_description_strings


def get_open_port() -> int:
    import socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(("", 0))
    s.listen(1)
    port = s.getsockname()[1]
    s.close()
    return port


def make_application(*, static_wrapper):
    # Module-level function for pickle-ability
    if static_wrapper is not None:
        application = static_wrapper(your_asgi_app)
    return application


class ChannelsLiveServer:
    port = get_open_port()
    host = "localhost"
    static_wrapper = ASGIStaticFilesHandler
    serve_static = True

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        for connection in connections.all():
            if connection.vendor == "sqlite" and connection.is_in_memory_db():
                raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                    "ChannelsLiveServer can not be used with in memory databases"
                )

        self._live_server_modified_settings = modify_settings(ALLOWED_HOSTS={"append": self.host})
        self._live_server_modified_settings.enable()

        get_application = partial(
            make_application,
            static_wrapper=self.static_wrapper if self.serve_static else None,
        )
        endpoints = build_endpoint_description_strings(
            host=self.host, port=self.port
        )

        self._server = DaphneServer(
            application=get_application(),
            endpoints=endpoints
        )
        t = threading.Thread(target=self._server.run)
        t.start()
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(0.10)
            if self._server.listening_addresses:
                break
        assert self._server.listening_addresses[0]

    def stop(self) -> None:
        self._server.stop()
        self._live_server_modified_settings.disable()

    @property
    def url(self) -> str:
        return f"ws://{self.host}:{self.port}"

    @property
    def http_url(self):
        return f"http://{self.host}:{self.port}"

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def channels_live_server(request, live_server):
    server = ChannelsLiveServer()
    request.addfinalizer(server.stop)
    return server
```

Comment: Can you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that works with this but not my answer?

Comment: @aaron "minimal" is, unfortunately, not quite possible with django.

Comment: @aaron [Here is a POC](https://github.com/nrbnlulu/channels_pytest_liveserver)

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a `channels_live_server` fixture based on the implementations of:

- [`live_server`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/blob/1f3708aba85afde971d02c70c12a7855f1af12a1/pytest_django/fixtures.py#L513-L514) fixture, which instantiates

  - [`LiveServer`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/blob/1f3708aba85afde971d02c70c12a7855f1af12a1/pytest_django/live_server_helper.py#L4) helper, which starts `LiveServerThread`, and
- [`ChannelsLiveServerTestCase`](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/985f1763edc05fcb00bd4c331c9a67d8627300ee/channels/testing/live.py#L21), which starts `DaphneProcess`.

**@medihack** implemented it at https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/issues/1027:

> ```py
> from functools import partial
> from channels.routing import get_default_application
> from daphne.testing import DaphneProcess
> from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import ASGIStaticFilesHandler
> from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
> from django.db import connections
> from django.test.utils import modify_settings
>
>
> def make_application(*, static_wrapper):
>     # Module-level function for pickle-ability
>     application = get_default_application()
>     if static_wrapper is not None:
>         application = static_wrapper(application)
>     return application
>
>
> class ChannelsLiveServer:
>     host = "localhost"
>     ProtocolServerProcess = DaphneProcess
>     static_wrapper = ASGIStaticFilesHandler
>     serve_static = True
>
>     def __init__(self) -> None:
>         for connection in connections.all():
>             if connection.vendor == "sqlite" and connection.is_in_memory_db():
>                 raise ImproperlyConfigured(
>                     "ChannelsLiveServer can not be used with in memory databases"
>                 )
>
>         self._live_server_modified_settings = modify_settings(ALLOWED_HOSTS={"append": self.host})
>         self._live_server_modified_settings.enable()
>
>         get_application = partial(
>             make_application,
>             static_wrapper=self.static_wrapper if self.serve_static else None,
>         )
>
>         self._server_process = self.ProtocolServerProcess(self.host, get_application)
>         self._server_process.start()
>         self._server_process.ready.wait()
>         self._port = self._server_process.port.value
>
>     def stop(self) -> None:
>         self._server_process.terminate()
>         self._server_process.join()
>         self._live_server_modified_settings.disable()
>
>     @property
>     def url(self) -> str:
>         return f"http://{self.host}:{self._port}"
>
>
> @pytest.fixture
> def channels_live_server(request):
>     server = ChannelsLiveServer()
>     request.addfinalizer(server.stop)
>     return server
> ```

Comment: Why do you start daphne on another proccess?

Comment: That's what `ChannelsLiveServerTestCase` does.