# Running ChannelsLiveServerTestCase does not create database for browser

Tags: django, testing, channel, asgi

I tried using pytest to test my frontend Django code with Selenium. In order to do that, a server has to be mocked which is when I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73140518/channelsliveservertestcase-equivalent-for-pytest) StackOverflow question, asking for the *ChannelsLiveServerTestCase equivalent for pytest*.

Since the code didn't work when browsing to the server, showing the yellow Django error page (`connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "test" does not exist`), I tried isolating the issue by removing complexity and using unittest's `ChannelsLiveServerTestCase` instead, following `channels` official [tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_4.html). It however yielded the same results.

It seems like the database is not being created properly for the frontend. What's weird is, that within the function, database calls can be made normally and the `test` database exists (checked with `pdb`). But as soon as the web server is browsed to using Selenium, the yellow error page shows up again – almost as if the asgi server is running in a completely different thread, unable to access the database?

I trimmed down the issue to the minimum and created a small repository for easily reproducing the issue: https://github.com/alfonsrv/django-asgitest
Any idea where I'm going wrong? Thanks